# 'TEST' is not supported by the language

Tags: c#, methods, c++-cli, visual-c#-express-2010

When I call a the C++ function:

```
public ref class TEST_CLASS
{
    void TEST(void (*func)())
    {
        (*func)()
    }
};
```

in C#:

```
TEST_CLASS t = new TEST_CLASS();
t.TEST(f);
```

I get the error:

> 'TEST' is not supported by the language

What would be causing this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: `TEST` really is a very very very common word. At least make it MYTEST to ensure it's not a pre-proc issue.

Comment: Try removing and re-adding the references from the C# project to the C++ project, and rebuilding both projects.

Comment: Check this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/03bdca3b-22b3-4f48-b146-5d89b3a288df *C# can't handle pointers to managed objects* Is the issue with `(*func)`?

Comment: @thekashyap Thanks for the suggestion, however it didn't work.

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2170486/76217

Comment: ref is not a valid keyword to define a class in c#. make sure you compile in c++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I call a the C++ function:

That's not C++ code, you wrote a C++/CLI class.  Note the *ref class* keyword.  You declared the method to take a C function pointer.  That's fine in the C++/CLI language, it lets you mix native and managed code constructs, but *not* fine to a language like C# or VB.NET.  They insist that you use the managed version of a function pointer, a *delegate*.

There's already a delegate type in the .NET framework that matches the signature of your C function pointer, MethodInvoker.  But let's assume you want to extend on the signature and add, say, your own arguments and return type:

```
public ref class TEST_CLASS
{
public:
    delegate void TEST_delegate();

    void TEST(TEST_delegate^ func)
    {
        func();
    }
};
```

Picking that name kinda hurt.